# tinymce change default style

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, tinymce-6

im trying to use tinymce to add and edit a blog with a different default style, i managed to load the font and text size when the editor loads but it doesnt apply to the code unless i select the text and apply the style again

for example this:

[image]

should see like this without user interactions

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to include some css files to you're config

example

```
tinymce.init({
selector: 'textarea.editme',    
content_css: ['/css/style2.css','/css/cfcms.css'],
```